# vpn connection to an azure virtual network

Tags: vpn, azure, eap

I have to connect to a Azure VNet, Which uses a certificate to authenticate that has been provided to me. When i try to connect to the VNet i get below error

**The Extensible Authentication Protocol type required for authentication of the remote access connection is not installed on your computer. (Error 850)**

[image]

From one of the blogs [setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-an-azure-virtual-network](https://jan-v.nl/post/setting-up-a-vpn-connection-to-an-azure-virtual-network) i see this can be corrected by selecting Microsoft:Smart card or other certificate as the Extensible authentication protocol in the security settings of the connection. But i dont see this listed in my Windows 10 laptop, is there a way to get this included as an option.

[image]

Comment: May I know if there is an update on your side?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this article](https://sysadminspot.com/server-administration/error-connecting-to-virtual-private-network-pptp-error-850-the-extensible-authentication-protocol-type-required-for-authentication/) to select the correct authentication protocol. If it is a Microsoft PPTP implementation then try the following configuration. Make sure you have enabled the tunnel type SSTP on the Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Xiong, I have seen this link before and had verified the settings, this when set asks me for user name and password, but the access shared to me is certificate based. When the default Azure VNet is done it adds a WAN Miniport (IKEv2) this did not give me any options to change in the property. Hence i added the VNet VPN setting manually by setting the properties which did not help

Comment: Do you use IKEV2 VPN tunnel instead of SSTP tunnel on the Azure VPN P2S connection?

Comment: The Azure VPN is setup to use SSTP, on another machines we when a VNet connection added we get this connected via SSTP and but on my machine when the VNet connection added it defaults to IKEV2 VPN .

Comment: It seems that the issue comes from your specific machine.